# Google OAuth id_token instead of access token

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, postman

I am trying to get the Google API Oauth process working in Postman, specifically for GMAIL. The below code works just fine now.

However, despite much of the process and syntax being copied from here: [Google API Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest) I am returning an `id_token` not the `access_token` I need. Any ideas?

The code has been copied from another post on here and tweaked.

```
var navigator = {};
var window = {};
eval(pm.environment.get("jsrsasign-js"));

var kid = pm.environment.get('kid');
var scope = pm.environment.get('scope');
var iss = pm.environment.get('iss');
var privateKey = pm.environment.get('privateKey');

const header = {"alg" : "RS256", "typ" : "JWT", "kid" : kid};

const claimSet =
{
  "iss": iss,
  "scope": scope ,
  "aud":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "exp": KJUR.jws.IntDate.get("now + 1hour").toString(),
  "iat": KJUR.jws.IntDate.get("now").toString()
}

console.log(`header: ${ JSON.stringify(header)}`);
console.log(`claim set: ${ JSON.stringify(claimSet) }`);

var jwt = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign(header.alg, header, claimSet, privateKey);

console.log(jwt);
pm.environment.set('jwt', jwt);
```

I have reviewed as much related documentation I can find but there is very little I can find on why you would return an `id_token` when the documentation states it should return the `access_token`.

Comment: Reading through the docs, it does appear this should be returning an access_token, not an id_token which I would expect from other grant types.  If its working, I wonder if its just an error in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks Mikee, it's reassuring to see someone else has looked at the documentation and come to the same conclusion, the question is, how do I resolve it? Would getting in touch with Google help? I've not had much in the way of dealings with Google tech support. Thanks

Comment: Not sure you will be able to resolve it if its a documentation issue.  All  you can do is let them know, and hope they do something about it.  I don't have any dealings with Google, so I can't even tell you the contact details.